# Show all progress of Download manager android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Im trying to create a simple application that show every progress of Download Manager class. I tried to use DownloadManager.Querry to get info but every solution about it in here need the downloadId like a filter.

```
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterById(downloadId);
```

So i removed the statement setFilter but it still did not work.
Anyone have solution for that???

Comment: see `DownloadManager#query` method

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798569/show-download-manager-progress-inside-activity