# ContentResolver openInputStream downloads the file in the background

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, android-contentresolver

So I'm trying to download a huge file. So naturally my first step is to open the stream

```
RNFetchBlob.RCTContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(fromUri));
```

My problem is that this instead of working quickly and just opening the stream, it in fact downloads the thing in the background. How do I know? Well this command blocks for like 5 minutes and then when I read from the stream, it's instantaneous.

Could I make this action prevent from download in the background? I want to inform the user about the progress and not just wait.

Edit: to make clear, I'm using a content:// URI for the resource

Comment: Found any solution? I got the same problem while importing 116MB File from GDrive - my app "stalls" on openInputStream. I may start a thread for this but who knows if that call ever finishes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong method to read a file over the network, you need to use network-specific methods.

```
HttpURLConnection request = 
    (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(Uri.parse(fromUri)).openConnection());
// Connect to the server, expect a delay and draw a progress bar
request.connect();
// This will read HTTP headers with content length, expect another delay
// Must be called before request.getContentLength()
request.getInputStream();
// Get the size of your file, to draw your progress bar properly
long total = request.getContentLength();
// Now you can finally start reading the data
InputStream input = request.getInputStream();
```

Comment: thanks, going to try! one minor thing - my URI is a content:// thing, hopefully it works for that as well :)

Comment: That would be a problem, `HttpURLConnection` only handles `http://` and `https://` URIs. You cannot do that with `content://` URI, it is downloaded by the content provider code, not by your app code, and the app cannot control the download progress.

Comment: so there's no way to get the download progress and no one in the android community complained about that?  (I googled quite extensively)

Answer (score 0):

For long-running HTTP downloads you can use [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) and show download progress e.g. like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15795872/6950238) question of [Victor Laerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965189/victor-laerte):

> ```
>     String urlDownload = <YOUR_URL>;
>     DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload));
>
>     request.setDescription("Testando");
>     request.setTitle("Download");
>     request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
>     request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
>     request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"teste.zip");
>
>     final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
>
>     final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
>
>     final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
>
>     new Thread(new Runnable() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void run() {
>
>             boolean downloading = true;
>
>             while (downloading) {
>
>                 DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
>                 q.setFilterById(downloadId);
>
>                 Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
>                 cursor.moveToFirst();
>                 int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
>                         .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
>                 int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
>
>                 if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
>                     downloading = false;
>                 }
>
>                 final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);
>
>                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>
>                     @Override
>                     public void run() {
>
>                         mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
>
>                     }
>                 });
>
>                 Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, statusMessage(cursor));
>                 cursor.close();
>             }
>
>         }
>     }).start();
> ```

Comment: hello, just making sure, will that work for content:// addresses?

Comment: Seems `DownloadManager` [content:// frendly](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/downloadmanager-part-1/): *The important thing which facilitates that is the Uri that DownloadManager returns is actually a content://... Uri which is very friendly to other apps andf allows them to easily access the content through as `ContentProvider` provided by `DownloadManager`*.

Comment: @Novellizator Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30671548/6950238) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14798569/6950238) questions and answers.

Comment: So in the end it looks like it's not that easy. tried your approach, and got: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3D43`

Comment: @Novellizator What  is your `fromUri` kind?

Comment: retrieved from pile pickers when getting the google drive document